# Some JS loading and others not

Tags: javascript, loading

I have 2 javascripts registered to a page. One being for google maps api and the other being the initialization function to get the map loaded and created. Now whichever one I put first will successfully work, but whichever I put second will not load properly. So If i put the googleapi first, firebug will tell me initialize doesn't exist and vise versa. So how can i get both to be loaded successfully. Below is the page and JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.652073, -79.382293);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }
    </script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Header" runat="server">
        <ucHead:UC_Header runat="server" ID="UC_Header" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div class="sidePanel">
        <ucMenu:UC_Menu runat="server" ID="UC_Menu" />
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the </html> missing in your source code or only your paste? Everything looks fine with the rest of the code...

Comment: What content is going in UC_HEader?

Comment: @jbabey Missed it in the paste that's all ...

Comment: @dstarh Just an image for the website, the <head> is not redefined in there

Comment: ok, wanted to ensure that it wasn't more script being added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must **close** your script tags...

You **cannot** do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />
```

It **must** look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ></script>
```

Comment: Nailed it, my map is showing up perfectly now! Thanks a lot! Any reasoning on why the script has to be closed with another tag and not simply a /> at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `</script>` tag after the googleapis.com script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" /></script>
```